# String Builder-removing duplicate values

Tags: stringbuilder

I have written this small code where i am getting values from lstmodel2 components.

```
 StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < lstmodel2.getSize(); i++) {
               String[] exsplt=lstmodel2.get(i).toString().split("\\.");
               sb.append(exsplt[0]);
               sb.append(" ,");
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
```

sb gives me

> axledetails ,axledetails ,contacts ,contacts ,material_master
>   ,supplier_master ,

I want to eliminate the duplicate entries from the String Builder so that the output would be

> axledetails ,contacts ,material_master ,supplier_master ,

Kindly give some suggestion how to do this.

Comment: I Suggest using a Set<String> intermediately and checking .contains() before actually appending.

Comment: ya i used set<string> and set doesn't store the duplicate values into it.So without checking for .contains(), i got my result.

Comment: Want me to add that as an answer then?

Comment: ya sure..well thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Set like this:

```
Set<String> ss = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < lstmodel2.getSize(); i++) {
     String[] exsplt=lstmodel2.get(i).toString().split("\\.");
     ss.add(exslpt[0]);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that technically sets are not ordered, so it may be wise to continue to retain the array and use `Set#contains` to check as you go. Some `Set` imperative may be iterable in insert order, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
          String ss;
            for (int i = 0; i < lstmodel2.getSize(); i++) {
               String[] exsplt=lstmodel2.get(i).toString().split("\\.");
               ss=exsplt[0]+",";
               if(ss.contains(exsplt[0])){
               sb.append(exsplt[0]);
               sb.append(" ,");
               }

            }
            System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: it seems that contains() is a method of java.lang.string not of java.lang.StringBuilder

Comment: the result is same.there is no effect on the output.